# Example to a Total Set

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

According to Kreyzig in Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications, a *total set* in a normed space $X$ is a subset $M  \subset X$ whose span is dense in $X$.

I wonder if someone could give me an actual example of a *total set*: for example, a total set of Euclidean normed space $\mathbb{R}^3$

Thank you!

Comment: In finite dimensions,  $M$ is a total set if and only if it contains a basis of $X$. The interesting examples occur in the infinite-dimensional cases.

Comment: Since Kreyzig loves those sequence spaces, the collection of sequences $e_i=\{\delta_{ij}\}_j$ where $i\in\mathbb N$ is total for $\ell^p$ with $1\leq p<\infty$ and $c_0$.

Answer (score 1):

In finite dimensions, being a total set just means that $M$ contains a basis for $X$.

The interesting examples are all infinite-dimensional.

One of the basic examples is: $X$ is the set of real-valued continuous function on $[0,1]$, with the norm $\|f\|=\int_{0}^1 |f(x)|\,dx$,  and $M=\{f_i\in X\mid f_i(x)=x^i\}$.

In this case, the span of $M$ is all polynomials, and the fact that the span is dense in $X$  means that you can approximate any continuous function $f$ on $[0,1]$ arbitrarily well will a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Another elementary example is given by the following. Let $\mathcal L_2(\mathbb R)$ denote the space of square-integrable functions on $\mathbb R$ and denote by $\chi_A$ the identity function for any subset $A\subset\mathbb R$.

Then, the set $\{\chi_I:I\subset\mathbb R,\,\text{a bounded interval}\}$ is total in $\mathcal L_2(\mathbb R)$.